# md-toolbar cuts off from right when resizing screen width

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am using material design for angular 2 and every time I reduce the width of the screen, the bar gets cut from the right and gives me extra whitespace.
[navbar img small width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSg9y.png)

[navar img original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVGc6.png)

Here is my code

```
    <md-toolbar color="primary">
        <span>
        Crayons and Clay</span>
        <span class="fill-remaining-space"></span>
        <div fxLayout="row" fxShow="false" fxShow.gt-sm>
            <button md-button routerLink='' >Home</button>
            <button md-button routerLink='/ourschool' >Our School</button>
            <button md-button routerLink='/communityevents'>Community Events</button>
            <button md-button routerLink='/admission'>Admissions</button>
            <button md-button routerLink='/contact'>Contact</button>
        </div>
        <button md-button [md-menu-trigger-for]="menu" fxHide="false" fxHide.gt-sm>
         <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
        </button>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-menu x-position="before" #menu="mdMenu">
        <button md-menu-item routerLink="/signin">Sign in</button>
        <button md-menu-item routerLink="/dashboard">Inquiry</button>
    </md-menu>

<style>
    .fill-remaining-space {

      flex: 1 1 auto;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `md-toolbar` inside another div with 100% width and `flex-shrink` & `flex-grow` set to 0. Also set a `min-width` for your toolbar.

> In your component.css:

```
.fill-remaining-space {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.header {
    min-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-grow: 0;
}
```

> ... and in your component.html:

```
<div class="header">
    <md-toolbar color="primary" layout-fill>
        <span>Crayons and Clay</span>
        <span class="fill-remaining-space"></span>
        <div fxLayout="row" fxShow="false" fxShow.gt-sm>
            <button md-button routerLink=''>Home</button>
            <button md-button routerLink='/ourschool'>Our School</button>
            <button md-button routerLink='/communityevents'>Community Events</button>
            <button md-button routerLink='/admission'>Admissions</button>
            <button md-button routerLink='/contact'>Contact</button>
        </div>
        <button md-button [md-menu-trigger-for]="menu" fxHide="false" fxHide.gt-sm>
            <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
        </button>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-menu x-position="before" #menu="mdMenu">
            <button md-menu-item routerLink="/signin">Sign in</button>
            <button md-menu-item routerLink="/dashboard">Inquiry</button>
        </md-menu>
</div>
```

---

Here is a working plunker: [**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/C2159IvR0S8at8By3WSg?p=preview)